# Why Is My HTML and CSS Code Not Running Properly On The Internet?

Tags: html, css

I recently added some text effects to my website in HTML and CSS. It runs perfectly on VS Code live sever but whenever I upload the code files on to my cpanel, the effects just seem to go away when I actually click and go on my website and I am not sure why. Does anyone know a fix for this? Here is my website [julianwsanchez.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMrQ8.png)

And this how it is supposed to look: [image]

How It Looks When I open it: [image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot how it's supposed to look like? Looks like I'm seeing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The output I'm seeing on your site matches the output of the code snippet here, effects and all.

Check to see if you have some browser extension that affects the way a site might look (e.g. a dark mode extension). Also, try going to your site in a different browser and/or in Incognito mode.

Comment: That's weird. So I haven't looked at my browser extensions but I tried going on my website on my phone using safari and the text 'Florida State University' is just in black and very tiny. I also tried opening the link through my instagram page and the text 'Florida State University' is just off the page so I am not exactly sure what to do. I did try incognito mode on my computer and that worked.

Comment: What browser (and version number) are you using to check the desktop version of your site?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome Version 101.0.4951.54. Someone earlier suggested using Ctrl-Shift-R to reload the site so I see it perfectly now. However when I run it on safari on my phone it messes up for me.

Comment: Good to hear that it's working on Chromium based browsers, at least -- I've checked it on my own android phone running Chrome, and it looks fine there too. The remaining issues you're seeing on mobile Safari might also be down to the browser caching an earlier version of your code.  Try going into Safari's settings and deleting the cache it holds for your site.

Answer (score 0):

it Works for me just fine, both the link given, and the files running on localhost
You might need to do a hard reload.
try `Ctrl-Shift-R` on chrome when viewing the page.
This clears the browsers cache for that webpage,
alternative: open the web page in another browser.

Comment: Hi. I think the issue that I am mainly having is when it is running on a phone. Would it be possible for you to also check and see if it runs properly on your device?

Comment: Yes it works for me, 'Florida State University' colour is moving and it looks just like the first picture I am on motorola android using duckduckgo browser

Comment: Huh that's very weird. I guess it might just be something with my phone because I do not know why my website looks different on different devices

Comment: It works for safari on ipad also